# PATH variables empty in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, environment-variables

I'm trying to access items in my PATH environment variable from my electron instance, when I run it with `npm start` while developing it through node.js I get all the expected variables, but when I run the electron application with my resources inside I'm left with only usr/bin

This is how it looks like when I run it from npm:[image: ran from npm]

And this is how it looks when run from the electron mac application precompiled: 
[image: Electron precompiled]

Does anyone know why this could be the case? And if I can do anything to reach my normal PATH variables

UPDATE:
After a lot of research I found out that GUI applications ran from finder or docker in Mac OSX use different environment variables compared to if they are ran from the terminal:
[This can be edited through plist files, either globally or application specific](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications)

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Did you manage to get the default PATH variables in your electron?

Comment: @JaviOverflow I was unable to get the path variable into the application if it remained as a docker app, my ugly solution was to create a shell script and run it from there instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fix-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-path) package. Works perfectly!

```
const fixPath = require('fix-path');

console.log(process.env.PATH);
//=> '/usr/bin'

fixPath();

console.log(process.env.PATH);
//=> '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin...'
```