# Unable to fix Node Path in packaged Electron App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm building a simple Electron app for MacOS (using React as the frontend). The purpose of the app was to make executing certain terminal commands a lot easier (using `child_process.spawn`. Primarily I am interested in using the [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm) Salesforce CLI commands.

When I run the app in dev, everything works fine. However when I package the app, the PATH variable gets changed and I'm no longer able to locate the `sfdx` library. (*note it is still able to find `git` commands though).

I found a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067127/path-variables-empty-in-electron) and a [bug report](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7688) in GitHub, both of which recommend the use of the [fix-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-path) package. This is where I run into another issue. According to the docs, I should import the package like this:

```
import fixPath from 'fix-path';
```

However when I do that inside of my `electron.js` file I get this error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. I've seen other resources that use `require` to bring in the package:

```
const fixPath = require('fix-path');
```

But again, when I do that I get this error `require() of ES Module not supported`.

I tried adding `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` file, but that breaks my app as well.

I feel like there is something simple that I am missing here, but can't seem to figure out. I believe that if I could import and use the `fix-path` package, then this would solve my problems. But if that isn't possible, does anyone know of a way for me to fix the path in my app so that it works in prod?

Thank you in advance!

Some extra details:
The two dependencies I check for are `git` and `sfdx`. The following image shows where both of those live on my machine:

[image]

And this is the response to the same commands within the packages asar file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, it looks like `fix-path` made a move to ESM during the last release. Because I am using CJS modules I just needed to install version 3 of `fix-path` by running `npm install fix-path@3.0.0 --save`